# SQL statement to return non-intersection records

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I was recently asked this question and was a little stumped so I want to ask the experts...

Given two tables A & B, I want to return all the values from A and B that do not overlap.  Think of two overlapping circles; how do we return all the data that is NOT in the overlapping center section?  And, I had to use ANSI Standard SQL rather than Oracle syntax.

Assuming we want **everything** exclusive to both A & B, my answer was

```
  select *
  from A 
  cross join B
  minus
    (select a.common_column from a
     intersect
     select b.common_column)
```

Does this look correct, or even close?  If it is correct, is there a more efficient way to do this?

BTW - my solution was soundly rejected....

Thank you!

Comment: Looks close.  I'd go with a `union all` instead of a cross join for the outer query.

Comment: Why do you perform a cross join? This will create the cartesian product of A and B. Assuming A and B contain more than one column, this query won't compile (because A cross join B returns NxM columns whereas the second part returns 1 column).

Comment: Yeah, you don't want a `cross join`.... Either do a `union all` and then an `except` on the `intersect`, or just do a `union all` on `select col from A except select col from B` and `select col from B except select col from A`

Comment: @JackManey, keywords `except` and `minus` do the same thing, but Oracle supports the keyword `minus`.

Comment: @DanBracuk, thank you for your rapid response.  Yes, replacing Cross Join with Union All is correct.  I got all wrapped around the axle thinking somehow the two tables had no commonality but, of course, that cannot be so since the do share some records.  Ugghhhh...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Given the tables A and B, you are looking for (A U B) - (A & B). In other words, you need A union B minus their intersection. Remember A and B must be union-compatible for this query to work. I would do:

```
(select * from A 
 union 
 select * from B
) 
minus
(select * from A 
  intersect
 select * from B
)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be full outer join?

```
select coalesce(A.col, B.col)
from A full outer join B on A.col = B.col
where A.col is null or B.col is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

For computing a set symmetric difference, you can use a combination of `MINUS` and `UNION ALL`:

```
select * from (
  (select * from A 
   minus
   select * from B)
  union all
  (select * from B
   minus
   select * from A)
)
```

Comment: Logically this is correct. But the full outer join solution is more efficient - ie fewer passes over the table.

Comment: @BobC Usually, I only run this as an ad-hoc query, so I don't worry too much about performance. And I find this solution much more readable and quicker to write than the full outer join, but YMMV.

Comment: I care very much about performance (it's my job) :)  So I just like to point these things out :)

Comment: Yes, this solution works as well although as already pointed out not the most efficient.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select all the data from both tables, except where they overlap, and then combine the data with a union. The code provided should work for your example.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Table2
  ) 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT * FROM Table2
    EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Table1
  )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since the subqueries will produce disjoint sets of tuples, `union all` would return the same result set and might result in better performance.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `select *` in your second query - otherwise, this will return a parse error unless table1 and table2 only contain the single column `item`.

Comment: I was not even aware Oracle has an EXCEPT function.  Something for me to learn.  Thanks!

Whoops - looks like MINUS works in Oracle while EXCEPT works in other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your query was rejected because it is syntactically incorrect:  the number of columns differ and it confuses `cross join` and `union all`.  However, I think you have the right idea for solving this.

You can easily fix this:

```
(select *
 from A 
 union all
 select *
 from B
) minus
(select *
 from A
 intersect
 select *
 from B
);
```

That is, combine everything using `union all` and then subtract the rows that occur in both tables.

Of course, if there is a single id, then you can use the id with `join` and other operations.

Comment: This is the solution I was aiming for....  I mucked it up by using Cross Join instead of Union All.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just like Frank Schmitt answered in the meantime:

Here it is including a data example:

```
WITH
table_a(name) AS (
          SELECT 'From_A_1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_A_2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_A_3'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_A_4'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_A_5'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_BOTH_6'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_BOTH_7'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_BOTH_8'
)
,
table_b(name) AS (
          SELECT 'From_B_1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_B_2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_B_3'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_B_4'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_B_5'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_BOTH_6'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_BOTH_7'
UNION ALL SELECT 'From_BOTH_8'
)
(SELECT * FROM table_a EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table_b)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table_b EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table_a)
ORDER BY name
;

name
From_A_1
From_A_2
From_A_3
From_A_4
From_A_5
From_B_1
From_B_2
From_B_3
From_B_4
From_B_5
```